# Managing Boost::any between shared libraries at runtime

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, segmentation-fault, shared-libraries

I'm making a C++ framework that is supposed to manage separately built custom modules, which are loaded at runtime as shared libraries. These modules have to communicate with each other using custom data, thus I'm using an unordered_map containing boost::any values that each module can use to set and read data.

The program has recently started to give a segfault error on shutdown, after a small change in destruction ordering of objects. After some tracking, I think I found the error: even though the unordered_map that holds all shared data is kept by the framework, each boost::any contains values that are created (necessarily) by code that resides in the shared libraries, since the framework has no idea of what values/types each key will contain during compilation.

What happens is that if I unload all shared libraries before I deallocate the map, boost::any generates a segfault when destroyed, since (I suppose) the pointer which contains its value has been already unloaded from memory. If I instead first delete the map and then deallocate all modules, no error shows up. Thus I am assuming that when a boost::any value is created and filled, its contents somehow gets allocated on some memory associated with the shared library, and when the shared library is closed trying to delete boost::any crashes everything.

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, boost::any> shared_data;
std::vector<Module> dynamically_loaded_modules;

// RUNTIME DURING SOME MODULE EXECUTION
shared_data["SomeKey"] = my_unknown_typed_data;

// ON PROGRAM EXIT
dynamically_loaded_modules.clear(); // Calls dlclose()
shared_data.clear(); // This crashes
// ---------------
shared_data.clear();
dynamically_loaded_modules.clear(); // This does not crash
```

My questions are the following:

- Is my interpretation of what is happening realistically possible? I don't know all that much about how shared libraries are managed by dlfcn.h
- Is deallocating the map and then the modules safe? Or should I have a way to make the modules explicitly delete each boost::any they created? Would I even need to do that?

Comment: "its contents somehow gets allocated on some memory associated with the shared library" --- there could be virtual functions or function pointers.

Comment: In general, it's a good idea to have destruction order mirror construction order. You load some modules, then create a map. You reverse the process by going backwards: destroy the map, then unload modules. The rationale is that objects created later can easily depend on objects created earlier, and the opposite dependency is less probable (though nothing is impossible with a little bit of cleverness).

Comment: @n.m. The modules' code is called through virtual functions, as that is the only way the framework can have an interface to talk with modules of which it knows nothing about.

Comment: @n.m. About your second point, that's what I thought I was doing: I create the map, then I load the modules, then the modules do their thing, then I unload the modules, then I destroy the map. But apparently that doesn't work right..

Answer (score 0):

Did you get the message of "Access violation reading location __vfptr"?
If so, i think the following statements can explain what happened and why.
Suppose map was created in sharedlibrary.dll, then push a boost::any object in map in userclient.dll.
The any object stored data whose type is int.Then a new template class type boost::any::holder< int > was created.The address of boost::any::holder< int > destructor is in range of userclient.dll's address.

Ok, now all is clear, you unload userclient.dll, the address of userlcient.dll is invalid. In finally, you destroy map in sharedlirary.dll, boost::any::holder< int > object's destrctutor should be called, but the address of boost::any::holder< int > destructor is invalid for userlicnet.dll is unloaded already. Then you would see the message of "Access violation reading location __vfptr".